# CreateCompatibleDC(IntPtr.Zero) returns IntPtr.Zero

Tags: c#, c++, gdi

I have the following code for a class. This is the initialize of a class.

Third Party DLL

```
 [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
 public static extern IntPtr CreateCompatibleDC(IntPtr hdc);

        protected void initialize()
        {
            if (_initialized)
            {
                return;
            }
            if (_hdc == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                _hdc = GDI32.CreateCompatibleDC(IntPtr.Zero);
                if (_hdc == IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    throw new GDIException("Failed to create compatible device context.");
                }
            }
            if (_hFontOld == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                _hFont = FontSettings.GenerateHFont(_fontSetting, _hdc, _dpi, _forceFixedPitch);
                _hFontOld = GDI32.SelectObject(_hdc, _hFont);
            }
            _initialized = true;
            updateHeightAndWidth();
        }
```

Sorry I didn't post the Dispose. Here it is!. This is a 3rd party DLL causing this error every 3- 4 hrs on production. Our company uses this 3rd party software. This error didn't happen before the upgrade.
    Third Party DLL.

```
protected virtual void Dispose(bool isDisposing)
    {
        if (_isDisposed)
        {
            return;
        }
        releaseOldBitmap();
        if (_hFont != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            if (_hFontOld != IntPtr.Zero && _hdc != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                GDI32.SelectObject(_hdc, _hFontOld);
            }
            if (GDI32.DeleteObject(_hFont))
            {
                _hFont = IntPtr.Zero;
            }
        }
        if (_hdc != IntPtr.Zero && GDI32.DeleteDC(_hdc))
        {
            _hdc = IntPtr.Zero;
        }
        _isDisposed = true;
    }

    ~TextPageRenderer()
    {
        Dispose(isDisposing: false);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(isDisposing: true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
```

This code in production works very well. But every 4hrs or so after some load on the server, GDI32.CreateCompatibleDC(IntPtr.Zero) returns IntPtr.Zero and the exception throw new GDIException("Failed to create compatible device context.") is thrown

Our code: This is how I use the 3rd party DLL in our code

```
#region ExternalText

public static DocumentsList ExternalText(Application obApp, int? _RequestCount, int[] _ItemTypeIDs, KeywordIdPairs _Keywords, Constraints _Constraints)
{ 
    var Results = new DocumentsList();
    TextSearchResults textSearchResults;
    var _SearchString = "";
    DateTime startDate;
    DateTime endDate;
    long startDocumentId;
    long endDocumentId;
    var textSearchOptions = new TextSearchOptions();
    var docQuery = obApp.Core.CreateDocumentQuery();

    var textProvider = obApp.Core.Retrieval.Text;
    try
    {
         var keywords = obApp.Core.KeywordTypes;
         startDocumentId = 1;
         endDocumentId = 10;
         docQuery.AddDocumentRange(startDocumentId, endDocumentId); 
        var documentList = docQuery.Execute(Convert.ToInt32(_RequestCount));

        _SearchString = "0916";

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(_SearchString))
        {
            foreach (var document in documentList)
            {
                var keyValueList = new KeyValueList<string, string>();


                if (document != null && document.DefaultRenditionOfLatestRevision != null && document.DefaultRenditionOfLatestRevision.FileType != null && document.DefaultRenditionOfLatestRevision.FileType.Extension == "ctx")
                {

                    textSearchResults = textProvider.TextSearch(document.DefaultRenditionOfLatestRevision, _SearchString, textSearchOptions);
                    foreach (var textSearchResult in textSearchResults)
                    {
                        var t = typeof(TextSearchItem);
                        PropertyInfo[] properties = t.GetProperties();
                        keyValueList.Add(ExternalTextRequest.DocID, document.ID.ToString());
                        keyValueList.Add(ExternalTextRequest.DocName, document.Name);
                        keyValueList.Add(ExternalTextRequest.DocumentType, document.DocumentType.Name);
                        foreach (PropertyInfo pi in t.GetProperties())
                        {
                            if (pi.Name == "SizeX")
                            {
                                keyValueList.Add(ExternalTextRequest.Width, pi.GetValue(textSearchResult, null).ToString());
                            }
                            else if (pi.Name == "SizeY")
                            {
                                keyValueList.Add(ExternalTextRequest.Height, pi.GetValue(textSearchResult, null).ToString());
                            }
                        }
                        Results.Add(keyValueList);
                    }
                }
                else
                {

                }
            }
        }

        return Results;
    }
    catch (UnityAPIException e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        throw ex;
    }
    return Results;

}
enter code here
```

The aboce snippet is my code using TextDataProvider 
I create an instance of TextDatProvider and call the textsearch from the API. The same code gets called more than 1000 times in 2 hrs. It is called for different search string, document ID's. TextSearch is heavily used.

How do I troubleshoot this problem. Could this be a memory leak? 
I cannot make it happen on test or development.
This is a .NET application that references a 3rd party component. This code is part of their component. Nothing changed except this 3rd party component which got upgraded.

Comment: DC are a system-wide limited resource irrespective of how much RAM you have.  You don’t show any code for destroying the DC and font.  Are you?

Comment: Run Taskmanager, go to "Details" tab, select "GDI objects". Most likely you are leaking resources, in which case GDI count will keep going up (the limit is 10,000)

Comment: In addition to @BarmakShemirani 's fine comment, you might want to check out _SysInternals Process Explorer_.  There you can track GDI handles amongst other goodies

Comment: @MickyD: Sorry I posted the code for dispose. Thank you for your help and patience. I am using iLSpy to decomplile their DLL.  I wonder if there a way to handle this on my end.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: Thank you for your input. I have it selected in the task manager. This is on the server probably not the client machine. Also, one more question..would a App pool reset clear up GDI objects?

Comment: Are you saying this is running in IIS?  If so, no, AppPool reset does not free GDI objects you have allocated unless your Dispose code is doing it.  However, I’m more concerned about AppPool auto timeout and recycling

Answer (score 1):

> Also, one more question..would a App pool reset clear up GDI objects?

You mentioned that your app is running in IIS. When an IIS AppPool is recycled or times out (usually after 20 minutes),  IIS unloads the AppDomain for the IIS app.  The AppDomain is given a chance to handle this event for clean-up purposes.

For ASP.NET apps this will be the `Application_End` method.  Be sure to release any GDI objects (including DCs and fonts) here.

Comment: There are no GDI objects for the worker process like you mentioned in the comment.

Comment: @user575219 I never said _”worker process”_.  I said you don’t show _how_ you are destroying GDI resources.  If you are calling this 3rd party dll with GDI resources you have allocated in IIS then that is `dangerous`

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I have updated the post to show how I am using the third party DLL. Please suggest.

Comment: Also, I am not saying that my code has no faults. But this is the code that existed and worked perfectly until last month. The only thing that changed is the upgrade for the 3rd party DLL.

Comment: @user575219 hmmm.  You might to contact their tech support then.  Does the problem persist if you use an earlier version of the dll?

Comment: I have no tried that since this is in Production. But I will try it and I did contact their support more than 3 weeks back. As usual with any big company they are researching the issue :). Anything that can change in my code? please feel free to point out.

Comment: @user575219 if as you say the only thing that has changed is a dll you have gotten from a 3rd party, that they compiled for you, and now your system doesn’t work in an environment you haven’t changed, then I would be rolling back to an old version.  Why didn’t you do this 3 weeks ago?  The flaw is with their code assuming you have told us everything.  You can prove it’s their fault in less than a minute `and` have a running system again

Comment: I totally get what you are saying. I like the way you say why didn't you do it 3 weeks ago:). There are two pieces to this 3rd party Hyland code. Its a DLL that I use in the code which talks to the API. The API connects to Hyland's App server. The app server has been upgraded to version 18 and so is the API DLL. The Hyland Appserver app pool  is the one that's crashing and has to be reset.  So even if rolled back the DLL, the app server upgrade needed to be rolled back. And then there is the Database part involved with this upgrade for the app server.

Comment: @user575219 haha no problem.  Yes I can see now there are a few things in the pipeline.  I don't know if you can deploy a new environment in a VM with the older version?  But yes, it will only prove which version may have a fault, it probably won't lead to any immediate fix if it lies with their code.  It's only diagnostic information.  If they are chasing it up leave it with them for the time being but if they appear to drag their feet or deny any problem, a working older VM serves as evidence that you could post on a blog to embarrass their marketing department :)

Comment: Thank you for the help. Adding a new Vm with the older version is what I told the support guys to consider. Appreciate your help.